# Deleting a line using regex

Tags: regex

I have a vcard that has the following entry.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Smith;John;;;
FN:John Smith
TEL;CELL;PREF:+919999999999
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Duck;Donald;;;
FN:Donald Duck
TEL;CELL;PREF:+919999999999
END:VCARD
```

I need to delete the third line of each contact, ie

```
N:Smith;John;;;
N:Duck;Donald;;;
```

I tried finding and pasting in text editor using regex. Find

```
2.1/nN:*FN:
```

and replace with

```
2.1/nFN:
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may match the 3rd line after `BEGIN:VCARD` using

```
^BEGIN:VCARD\R.*\R\K.+\R?
```

and replacing with an empty string.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `BEGIN:VCARD` - a literal string
- `\R` - any line break sequence
- `.*\R` - a whole line with the line break after it
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all the text matched so far
- `.+\R?` - 1+ chars other than line break chars (the whole line, `.+`)  and then an optional line break sequence.

[image]

**NOTE**

To remove a line starting with `N:`, you may simply use `^N:.*\R?` where `^` matches a line start, `N:` matches `N:`, `.*` grabs the whole line and `\R?` matches an optional line break sequence.

Comment: What should be the expression if I would like to swap the names? N:Smith;John;;; to N:John Smith;;;;

Comment: Assuming there are always two `;` characters present and two names. Search for `^N:([^;]+);([^;]+);` and replace with `N:$2 $1;;`.

Comment: N:$2 $1;; literally replaces the names to $2 and $1 instead of swapping the names. Am I missing something while executing the expression?

Comment: *"`$n, ${n}, \n` Returns what matched the subexpression numbered n. Negative indices are not alowed."* See: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Substitutions

Comment: @the_beginner You might need turn on some option to allow back references in your replacement statement. Otherwise try back referencing with the backslash instead of the dollar sign.

Comment: @the_beginner Before this solution in my answer, replace `^N:\K([^;\n]+);([^;\n]+);` with `$2 $1`.

Comment: @JohanWentholt I am using Geany editor. N++ isn't available for linux. I have enabled back referencing in Geany, but $ isn't the sign for back referencing. I will search for it.

Comment: @the_beginner If `$1` does not work, `\1` should (it is a POSIX originated syntax). If `\R` is not supported, use `(?:\r\n?|\n)`.